# How to avoid duplicate node?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am writing a java project to insert data in neo4j using a cypher query. I want to stop neo4j from creating a duplicate node, instead linking the other node with the existing node.

```
CREATE (n1:node {name:'Adam'})-[:born_in]->(n2:node {name:'USA'})
//and again 
CREATE (n1:node {name:'Adam'})-[:worked_at]->(n2:node {name:'Apple'})
```

I want to create one node of Adam and two other nodes i.e. `USA` and `Apple`. Are there any checks in java to avoid duplications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> best way to create relationship between two nodes is
>
> first get the two nodes.if they doesn't exists then create. Once
>   the nodes are loaded, then simply create a relationship between them

in your case, create your nodes with `MERGE` and then relationship

```
MERGE (n1:node {name:'Adam'})
MERGE (n2:node {name:'USA'})
MERGE (n1)-[r:born_in]->(n2)
```

this link will help you in understanding `MERGE`

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/

Comment: in my practice, even in such way duplicated nodes are still created. I guess it might related to high frequency of the merge operation ...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a general way to avoid adding duplicates:

```
MERGE (u:User { email: "me@you.com" }) 
SET u.name="Jon Smith" 
RETURN u
```

This works in both neo4j and redisgraph.

J